# Rails in time zone finding - not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have problem with zones in rails.

I have `CarRoute id: 22783, route_time: "2016-07-07 05:30:00"`
but in `CarRoute.find_by_id(22783).route_time is Thu, 07 Jul 2016 07:30:00 CEST +02:00`

So rails add 2h but when I want find by time this route is not works,

```
CarRoute.where(:id=>22783,:route_time=> DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, 7, 0, 0, 0)..DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month,  Date.today.day, 19, 0, 0, 0)) 
 => []
```

Enyone know how find this ?

Comment: Ok, so rails isn't "adding" 2hr - your data is usually stored in the db in UTC, this is because that's a good standard to have. You are probably then displaying it in your local timezone (where you get he 2hr time difference). so... to find it, you need to use the time in UTC

Comment: But DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0) is return in UTC Tue, 05 Jul 2016 07:00:00 UTC +00:00
I try Time.zone.local(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 5, 7, 0, 0).in_time_zone('UTC') but its looks strange for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rails stores everything in UTC, which means that whatever time zone you use when assigning a datetime, its converted to UTC. When active record loads a new record, that date is presented in the current time zone (Time.zone), that's why when you perform `CarRoute.find_by_id(22783).route_time` you get a CEST date, but if you go to your database you will see a UTC date.

The following should make it clear for you:

```
> Time.zone
  => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007ff6bd390100 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/UTC>>
> a = Account.first
  => #<Account id: 6 .....
> a.updated_at
  => Wed, 06 Jul 2016 18:47:32 UTC +00:00
> Time.zone = "EST"
  => "EST"
> a.reload
  ...
> a.updated_at
  => Wed, 06 Jul 2016 13:47:32 EST -05:00
```

When you use `DateTime.new` the date is created in utc:

```
> d = DateTime.new(2016,7,7)
  => Thu, 07 Jul 2016 00:00:00 +0000
> d.utc?
  => true
> a.updated_at.utc?
  => false
```

In your where query, you're starting at 7 UTC, which is 9 am CEST. Try something like:

```
DateTime.new(2016,7,7,7,0,0,0).change(offset: 'CEST')
```